# HTML.Partial() is not working when displaying it?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In Asp.net mvc 5. we have a login page which implements HTML.BeginForm() to post data to controller , if the username and password are incorrect, we are sending error back to the front end using partial views. Everything work fine, In case of error only error message is displayed on the screen and nothing else.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SingleSSOMPLogin(SSoStateModel model)
{
    //Check the Code with SP providers and Authorization server.
      if(model.SAMLAssertion.validMPData)
      {
        return RedirectToAction("SSOServiceMP" , "SAML");
      }else
      { 
         //Error message processed.
         model.errorMessage = SSOState.SAMLAssertion.errorMessage;
         return PartialView("_LoginError" , model);
      }
}
```

The view contain the following Code

```
<div class="peripheral">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-peripheral">
            @{Html.Partial("_LoginError", Model);}
            <div class="panel-heading clearfix">Please Log In</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="brand-logo eop-logo">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function changeImage() {
                            document.getElementById("Logo").src = '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/TopLogo.gif")';
                        }
                    </script>
                    <img id="Logo" width="200" src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/TopLogo.gif")' onerror="changeImage()" />


                    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true);}

                    <!--Ajax call to Controller-->
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("SingleSSOMPLogin", "Accounts"))
                    {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

                        <div id="group-email" class="form-group col-md-12 ">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Please enter your Email address" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                        </div>

                        <div id="group-password" class="form-group col-md-12">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Please enter your password" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Login</button>
                                <a id="forgot" href='@Url.Action("ForgotPassword","Accounts")' class="btn btn-link btn-sm pull-right">Forgot your password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Partial View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@if (Model.Result!= null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <strong>@Model.Result.errorMessage</strong>
    </div>
}
```

When Error occur, I get redirect to same view again with all query parameter gone and display only error message.

How to solve following issue?

Answer (score 1):

The partial view will return only the fragment you defined.
So when called from a "complete" view with

```
@{Html.Partial("_LoginError", Model);}
```

it will generate the corresponding part of the view.

In your situation what is most common is to add a model error and return the complete view (that must have a ValidationSummary section):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SingleSSOMPLogin(SSoStateModel model)
{
    //Check the Code with SP providers and Authorization server.
      if(model.SAMLAssertion.validMPData)
      {
        return RedirectToAction("SSOServiceMP" , "SAML");
      }else
      { 
         //Error message processed.
         ModelState.AddModelError("error", SSOState.SAMLAssertion.errorMessage);             
         return View(model);
      }
}
```

If you want to use the partial view you have to call it from an javacript ajax call and insert the response in your page. With jQuery it is something more or less like:

```
$.ajax({ url: <partial view url>,
         type: 'GET',
         success: function (result) {
           $(updateSelector).hide().html(result).effect("fade", "fast");
         }
      });
```

Comment: thanks, but when returning the view. It will also remove the query parameter, which are very important?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand correctly your question... when you do return View(model) the view will contain all the information in the model (from url query and your form data). You don't loose anything.

Comment: I mean: next received post will contain the same model information (except for user modifications in the form, of course)